# Can I place marker on map using Companion App?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-ground-zeroes

While you can place a marker by opening iDroid in-game and pressing circle button on the map (PS3, Japanese version), I have yet to find a way to do this via the Companion App. Have anyone figured out how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To place a marker on your map, simply touch and hold the desired target until the marker appears.

Calling choppers is done in the exact same fashion, with the only difference being: you have to select the "Call chopper" option first.